# SQL LENGTH Purpose

Tags: sql, oracle

I encountered a query that had the following code, The city in the table is Paris.

```
SQL >select INITCAP (cust_first_name | | ' ' | | 
UPPER (SUBSTR ( cust_city, 
-LENGTH(cust_city), 2))) 
FROM customers WHERE first_name = 'Abigail';
```

My question is on the length clause, as it looks like there is a negative symbol preceding it, but I am not sure what the purpose of it is.

Could someone break down this one for me?

The result of this Query is: `Abigail Pa`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm

Comment: Maybe i am not understanding, I see the purpose of the length given in the link provided, but nowhere does it show the "-length" as it does in the given query. I am wondering if there is a special purpose of the '-' or if that is simply a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really odd way of doing things!

When you use a negative number for the start position parameter of `SUBSTR`, it means count from the end of the string.

So in your query, for a cust_city of length N, the SUBSTR is starting at the Nth character to the left of the end of the string.

That effectively means the `SUBSTR` starts from the first character at the start of the string, meaning your query could be rewritten:

```
select initcap(cust_first_name||' '||upper(substr(cust_city, 1, 2)))
from   customers
where  first_name = 'Abigail';
```

Additionally, the `UPPER` is redundant; what is the point of forcing the first 2 characters of cust_city to be upper case, when the string it's appended to is going to `INITCAP` on the whole string?

Therefore, I'd write your query as follows:

```
select initcap(cust_first_name||' '||substr(cust_city, 1, 2))
from   customers
where  first_name = 'Abigail';
```

Much simpler and easier to understand IMHO!

Comment: Thank you, I asked the same question regarding the upper clause. This was a part of a practice exam i was taking and it did not make sense to me but i am still learning so i wasnt sure if i was just wrong.